# Why is my go lang string comparison not working as expected?

Tags: go

I am dipping my toe with `Go` and have written some code to check if **y** or **n** is input:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("(y / n): ")
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
text = strings.ToLower(text)

if strings.Compare(text, "y") == 0 { 
    fmt.Println("True")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Else")
}
```

When I run this code & type `y` (and press enter) I expect to see `True` but I get `Else` - can anyone see why?

Comment: ["ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter"](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.ReadString)

Answer (score 5):

You most likely want something like:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("(y / n): ")
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
text = strings.ToLower(text[0:len(text)-1])

if strings.Compare(text, "y") == 0 { 
   fmt.Println("True")
} else {
   fmt.Println("Else")
}
```

As the comment above says, `ReadString()` returns the delimiter as part of the string.  So you're getting "y\n" and comparing to "y" - the result is false.  (You might rather use the `Trim()` function to remove all whitespace from either side of the input,instead!)

Edit:   The `Trim()` suggestion should always be preferred over the original suggestion.  To do otherwise produces non-portable code, as illustrated in the comments to this answer.   The complete revised code:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("(y / n): ")
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')  
text = strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(text," \r\n"))

if strings.Compare(text, "y") == 0 { 
   fmt.Println("True")
} else {
   fmt.Println("Else")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried this but I'm getting the same result?

Comment: Works for me, I actually tested my change by C&P the revised code in the answer.

Comment: (Is it possible you are on windows, and getting the MS-style \r in your ReadString() return value as well?   If so, change the -1 to a -2, or better - use the Trim() function as I suggest.

Comment: `text = strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(text," \r\n"))`

Comment: Let me know if the second change works - that's super-quirky on the part of `strings` if so, IMHO...  or maybe not, depending on perspective.

Comment: I'd recommend using Scanner to prevent issues with platforms. https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner

Answer (score 3):

As @TimCooper pointed out in a comment, 
[*"ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter"*](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.ReadString).
That means, as your delimiter is `\n`, it will get included in the `text` read, so you need to consider that when making comparisons, or strip it out.

As revealed by the discussion on the other answer, simply stripping `\n` is not enough. This is probably because the line ending of user input from `stdin` may be different depending on the operating system. In UNIX it's `\n`, in Windows it's `\r\n`.
Here's a more portable solution:

```
if strings.TrimRight(text, "\r\n") == "y" {
```

I also changed the use of `strings.Compare` to a more direct, simpler comparison with `"y"` directly.